Thread suspend technique with out using suspend API in java
I am reading about thread in Java book by Cay S Horstman. Below is text snippet.

If you want to safely suspend a thread, introduce a variable
"suspendRequested" and test it in a safe place of your run method - in
a place where your thread does not lock objects that other threads
need. When your thread find that the "suspendRequested" variable has
been set, it should keep waiting until it becomes available again.

My question is
Suppose threadA is running and it wants to be suspended it will check "suspendRequested" and if it is set it will wait, this this point it is clear.  My question is who will set "suspendRequested" to true and how threadA will know it should start again? Kindly explain this

controllerThread sets the suspendRequested flag to true when it wants to pause threadA. threadA checks this flag if it's in run() method and, if it's set, it enters a waiting state using wait() or Thread.sleep(). To resume threadA, the controlling thread sets suspendRequested back to false and calls notify() to wake threadA up.

Thread.sleep() will not work.  wait and notify can only be called in a synchronized block, which is how they guarantee thread safety.  This short section of the Java Language Specification explains this clearly.

@spongebob Include a working code sample to prove your point.

Instead of using a boolean variable and implement a notification system for it, you can use a, e.g. a Lock, Semaphore, or Phaser in the first place.
